# Blank space after content only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, firefox

I would like to remove the blank space that shows only in Firefox, in Chrome everything works fine.

Note that the blank space appear after all the content and in resolution between **1001-1580px**

You can see the page on this link: https://consulta-placa-e4kdbawt1-wagnerloch.vercel.app/

This image shows the error:
[Blank space after content only in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8bGz.png)

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to see what is rendered there? We'd need a lot more context, and some code, to try and understand what is occurring or try to reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: As you can see in the image, there is nothing there. The HTML ends and then appear the blank space. But as I said, this just appear on Firefox. You can acess this link https://consulta-placa-e4kdbawt1-wagnerloch.vercel.app/ to test it. I think this appear because the elements are resized but in Chrome everything works fine.